# Using a for loop to test if number is odd

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a method that checks an array for how many odd numbers it contains. The idea is I use a for loop to test if a number is odd, and if it is, it then raises the variable b by one, and then it returns b as the number of odds. I wrote it like this:

```
for ( int a = 0, b = 0; values[a]%2==1;a++){
b++;
}

return b;
```

but it gives me an error "return b;
       ^
b cannot be resolved".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the b has no scope outside the loop, define int b=0, before the loop (it is a basic stuff).

Comment: BTW: `values[a]%2==1` tests that a number is odd and positive. If you want all odd numbers use `values[a] % 2 != 0` e.g. `-1 % 2` is `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `b` value to do need to check for the end of the array.  What you have similar to

```
for (int a = 0; a < values.length;a++)
    if(values[a]%2!=1)
        return a;

// currently throws an exception.
```

what you may have intended is to count the number of odd values which would look like this.

```
int count = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < values.length;a++)
    if(values[a] % 2 !=0)
        count++;
return count;
```

or

```
int count = 0;
for (int v: values)
    count += v & 1;
return count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable b is defined in for statement and is only visible in that code block.

try this

```
int b = 0;
for ( int a = 0; values[a]%2==1;a++){
b++;
}

return b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined b in the scope of your loop - it is not visible outisde for your return. You could rewrite like this:

```
int b = 0
for ( int a = 0; values[a]%2==1;a++){
b++;
}

return b;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming as you are trying to access variable outside the scope in which you have defined it.

```
// b is defined in this scope and available here only
for ( int a = 0, b = 0; values[a]%2==1;a++){

    b++;
}

// Nothing as b is available outside scope
return b;
```

To fix this issue just declare `b` in the larger scope.

```
int b=0;
for ( int a = 0; values[a]%2==1;a++){
    b++;
}

return b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers point out what is causing your compilation error.  It should also be noted that the algorithm is wrong.  The problem is that the loop terminates the first time that `values[a]%2==1` is `false`.  In other words, it counts the number of odd numbers *before the first even number* ... rather than the total number of odd numbers.

Comment: Yes, this is what I found even when I could get it to compile. How can I get around that? If/else statement??

Comment: Yes.  That is the simple way.  I won't give you the code since you will learn more by working it out for yourself.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 - The more valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/IfElse.shtml

Check out this tutorial. It should tell you everything you need to know and is a little simpler than your approach.